# Android studio app keeps closing

Tags: java, android, xml

okay so i am new to android studios, and i was messing around with a stupid fart noise app. My first attempt was a single button that played a noise now i have three buttons but the app won't open in the emulator. all it says is app keeps closing. i have tried to google every error in the log cat but nothing worked for me so far. I tried a couple different emulators but originally it worked so not sure what to change. the sound files are .mp3 not sure if that matters.

this is my log cat

> 04-10 11:41:16.090 2082-    2082/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: Micro detection mode: [mDetectionMode: [1]].
>   04-10 11:41:16.090 2082-2082/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: Using mInputStreamFactoryBuilder
>   04-10 11:41:16.096 2082-3754/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Starting detection.
>   04-10 11:41:16.096 2082-2158/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_starting com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@1f9150b
>   04-10 11:41:16.097 1304-2583/? W/APM_AudioPolicyManager: getInputForAttr() failed opening input: samplingRate 16000, format 1, channelMask 10
>   04-10 11:41:16.097 2082-2158/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord: Could not get audio input for session 1097, record source 1999, sample rate 16000, format 0x1, channel mask 0x10, flags 0
>   04-10 11:41:16.097 2082-2158/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/AudioRecord-JNI: Error creating AudioRecord instance: initialization check failed with status -22.
>   04-10 11:41:16.097 2082-2158/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/android.media.AudioRecord: Error code -20 when initializing native AudioRecord object.
>   04-10 11:41:16.097 2082-2158/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_started com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@1f9150b
>   04-10 11:41:16.098 2082-2158/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search E/ActivityThread: Failed to find provider info for com.google.android.apps.gsa.testing.ui.audio.recorded
>   04-10 11:41:16.098 2082-2082/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: onReady
>   04-10 11:41:16.101 2082-2158/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicrophoneInputStream: mic_close com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.z.c@1f9150b
>   04-10 11:41:16.103 2082-3754/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Detection finished
>   04-10 11:41:16.103 2082-3754/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorReporter: reportError [type: 211, code: 524300]: Error reading from input stream
>   04-10 11:41:16.103 2082-3754/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search W/ErrorProcessor: onFatalError, processing error from engine(4)
>                                                                                                 com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.speech.a.g: Error reading from input stream
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a.a(SourceFile:342)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.staticplugins.recognizer.i.a$1.run(SourceFile:1367)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85)
>                                                                                                  Caused by: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space.
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.Tee.g(SourceFile:2531)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ap.read(SourceFile:555)
>                                                                                                     at java.io.InputStream.read(InputStream.java:101)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.al.run(SourceFile:362)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.speech.audio.ak$1.run(SourceFile:471)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:428)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ak.run(SourceFile:66)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ax.run(SourceFile:139)
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133) 
>                                                                                                     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607) 
>                                                                                                     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761) 
>                                                                                                     at com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.util.concurrent.a.ad$1.run(SourceFile:85) 
>   04-10 11:41:16.103 2082-3754/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/AudioController: internalShutdown
>   04-10 11:41:16.103 2082-2310/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroRecognitionRunner: Stopping hotword detection.
>   04-10 11:41:16.114 2082-2082/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetector: Keeping mic open: false
>   04-10 11:41:16.114 2082-2082/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/MicroDetectionWorker: #onError(false)
>   04-10 11:41:16.114 2082-3753/com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox:search I/DeviceStateChecker: DeviceStateChecker cancelled

here is my .java file

```
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.view.View;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button button1,button2,button3;
private MediaPlayer fartSound1MP;
//private MediaPlayer fartSound2MP;
//private MediaPlayer fartSound3MP;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    fartSound1MP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fart01);
    //fartSound2MP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fart03);
    //fartSound3MP = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.fartsqueak01);

    button1.findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button2.findViewById(R.id.button2);
    button3.findViewById(R.id.button3);

    button1.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    fartSound1MP.start();
                }
            });
   /* button2.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    fartSound2MP.start();
                }
            });
    button3.setOnClickListener(
            new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    fartSound3MP.start();
                }
            }); */


      }
   }
```

here is my .xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
package="com.francisagostini.fart"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:paddingLeft="16dp"
android:paddingRight="16dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Click buttons for different fart noises!"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
    android:textSize="30sp"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fart1"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fart2"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Fart3"
        tools:ignore="HardcodedText" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Your farting problems are with AS or your app? Doesn't know why people insist on they're developing Android Studio... I've never seem this app. IDE is one (very basic) thing and APP is other, agree? Right. Your logcat says: com.google.android.apps.gsa.shared.exception.GsaIOException: Error code: 393238 | Buffer overflow, no available space. Probably you're doing something wrong as a reading strategy. Also, I see you didn't recycle your media player. Search about Media Player lifecycle, this is your problem. You have to release it. In Android it's not just instantiate mp and go clicking,no

Comment: please filter your logcat so it will show only your application context

Comment: It is your app is crashing. Not Android Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way you initialize the button is wrong. This is the correct way to initialize the view:

```
button1 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
button2 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button2);
button3 = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button3);
```

Comment: :) i love when i overlook the simple stuff... also thank you funny part is as soon as I see it i go wow why do i do this to myself.